# JQuery exception when select option with whitespaces

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with select option in html select element via JQuery. Next code demonstrate my problem:

```
$('select[name="location"] option[value=' + 'mercedes mercedes' + ']').attr('selected', true);
```

And i have simple html code for select with option value - "mercedes mercedes". When I run my script - i got exception:

> "Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [value=mercedes mercedes]
>   throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );"

When I delete whitespace - all is ok. Maybe anyone know - how to fix it?

Comment: Don't mix double quotes and single quotes a lot.  You will have to escape single quotes inside the outer single quotes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put quotes around your option :

```
$('select[name="location"] option[value="' + 'mercedes mercedes' + '"]')
```

Comment: I tried this approach and I don't know why the result of the selector is `#materialGroup option[value="NaN"]"`. Is there a restriction to this that its only allowed for numbers?

Comment: @newbie Your problem is probably elsewhere, but without code it's hard to tell

Answer (score 2):

```
$('select[name="location"] option[value=' + 'mercedes mercedes' + ']')
```

results in

```
$('select[name="location"] option[value=mercedes mercedes]')
```

which is not a valid selector. Since the value has a space, you have to enclose it in quotes (like the other answers show).

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

> **`value`**: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted **single** word or a quoted string.

If this is not a multiple select field, just call `.val`:

```
$('select[name="location"]').val('mercedes mercedes');
```

Comment: How do you quote it if it is on a variable?

Comment: @newbie: not sure what you mean, but probably the same way. You are just doing string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

The value with paces should be quoted in the selector:

```
$('select[name="location"] option[value="mercedes mercedes"]');
```

If you get that from a variable (most likely), you should do this:

```
$('select[name="location"] option[value="'+yourvariable+'"]');
```